# Capturing a sneaky Bane

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, spirits, werewolf-20th-anniversary

Our Kaganmadi just encountered a Bane last round, that is sneaky and tries to influence a Bête by whispering to them sneakily. Now we had stopped at a cliffhanger, having found out the following:

- A **Spirit Ward** does silence it and break the influence, possibly for the time the victim remains in it.
- The Spirit is rather good at dodging **Sense Wyrm**, having given us wildly conflicting readings at times, but enough evidence to try the ward, confirming it was a Spirit/Bane of sorts.

As other weapons in our Arsenal we have:

- a bunch of Bête that could get into the Umbra and drag all people there
- the same bunch could arguably tear the Bane a new one, provided we can force it to get to our claws
- Rite of Summoning (several)
- Rite of Binding (one)
- Rite of Cleansing (several)
- Spirit Speech (several)
- Truth of Gaia (several, including a Fetish)
- Scent of the true Form (one or more)
- A Bubasti mildly reeking of Wyrm (as Bubasti all do)
- Maybe 4 to 6 hours time to do what needs to be done till we have to get moving.

While we were hatching plans to try to "leave the bane behind" somehow trying to use the Umbra and the Spirit Ward. But surely we should have more options provided we could... Uhm... Force it bound into a rock?

**What rules would apply to bind said *unknown power* Bane without knowing its Name as of yet to a rock, mayhaps turning it into a Talen, and how could our arsenal make it easier for us to force the result?**

Comment: (The question title makes me think of *The Dark Knight Rises*: "Was getting caught part of your plan?")